# SVG imports with NextJS 13's new folder system (src/app)

Tags: svg, next.js

has anyone using Next 13 with /app folder managed to get svg imports to work or know how to?

I can get it to work with the old folder structure using `svgr/webpack` but can't on this new `src/app` folder structure

Comment: can you share any code example

Comment: to me as well it throws 37+ moderate severity vulnerabilities when installing SVGr on next 13 , most of it has to do with babel from what I see